# How to autoplay or loop slider images

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, image-slider

help me to `autoplay` image in **jquery  slider ?**

i watch this tutorial and try to make an image slider , for the customization i need loop this images

youtube url of slider - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2HLW4A40X8&t=5s

code is given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JQSlider</title>

  <style> basic styling <>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="right_img">
      
      <div class="slider-outer">
        <button class="prev">
          <img src="images/leftarrow.png" alt="">
      </button>
        <div class="slider-inner">
          <img  src="images/Rectangle - Copy.png" class="active">
          <img src="images/Rectangle1.png">
          <img src="images/Rectangle2.png">
          <img  src="images/Rectangle.png">
        </div>
        <button class="next">
          <img src="images/rightarrow.png" alt="">
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.next').on('click', function(){
        var currentImg = $('.active');
        var nextImg = currentImg.next();

        if(nextImg.length){
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      nextImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
    }
  });

  $('.prev').on('click', function(){
    var currentImg = $('.active');
    var prevImg = currentImg.prev();

    if(prevImg.length){
      currentImg.removeClass('active').css('z-index', -10);
      prevImg.addClass('active').css('z-index', 10);
    }
  
  });
});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  
    var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
    var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
    
    $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
    
    $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
    
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  background: #58DDAF;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>AutoPlay Slider</h1>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```